# Identify which mode is throwing an error

Tags: debugging, error-handling

I am attempting to edit a file. Emacs is preventing me from making the edit, and throwing: `Args out of range: #<buffer user.action.js>, 4965, 17721`. It is completely not obvious to me where this exception is coming from. How can I debug errors such as this one?

Comment: @Drew: the similarity between the two seems rather tenuous.

Comment: @stefan: Indeed; sorry. The question is essentially how to see what happened & why, when an error is raised - catch the error and show a call stack. A general answer is, as you suggested, to show a backtrace via `debug-on-error`. Seems like the question has been asked, but I don't find a good duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Enable debugging via `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` or in the menu `Options => Enter Debugger on Error`.